Implicit re-export not associating correct type
I'm trying to figure out a way in TypeScript to re-export protected members of the base class with public visibility, but otherwise unchanged without having to repeat the entire signature.
The following seems to work, but the types of Todos::update and Todos::filter are not correctly implied, parameters are any the return values are unknown.
export class CrudService<T, FILTER> {
  protected update(id: string, record: T): Observable<void> { ... }  // These methods are protected, as not all CrudServices may actually support them
  protected filter(f: Observable<FILTER> = of(undefined)): Observable<T[]> { ... }
  protected get(id: string): Observable<T>
}

export type Todo = { id: string, title: string, desc: string }
export type TodoFilters = { id: string, longerThan: number, page: number, count: number }

export class Todos extends CrudService<Todo, TodoFitlers> {
  public update; // Supported - not sure where I saw this syntax exactly, but it works, except implying the correct typing.
  public filter; // Supported

  // get is not supported for this class, so not reexported as public.
}

//Alternative would be along the lines of:
export class Todos extends CrudService<Todo, TodoFitlers> {
  public update(id: string, record: Todo): Observable<void> { return super.update(id, record); }
  public filter(filter: Observable<TodoFilter> = of(undefined)): Observable<Todo[]> { return super.filter(filter); }
}



Having to type out the entire signature would be really cumbersome and error-prone (most changes may be caught by the compiler, but what about changing the default value of the filters parameter for example?) in the real application, and would also prevent the ability to reuse code snippets across services (copy past the public re-exports, for example). Is there a proper way to do this?

• Does this question depend on rxjs? If so, please tag it as such and make sure the code explicitly imports the types/values you need. If not, please [edit] the question to remove references to of and Observable. • Please make sure your code is a [mre] without typos, so we can play with it in our IDEs easily. I see "fitlers" in there so I imagine you haven't passed this code through your own IDE before posting it; please do that and make sure it demonstrates what you're trying to demonstrate.

I don't think you actually have to re-define the methods, with implementations that return super.method(...arguments). Using declare public update(id: string, record: Todo): Observable<void>; and declare public filter(filter?: Observable<TodoFilter>): Observable<Todo[]>; should work

"what about changing the default value of the filters parameter?" - you shouldn't redefine those, even if calling the parent method - just declare the parameter as optional, and let the parent method figure out the default values.

No, the given examples are indeed based on rxjs, but the question is generic.

Then please [edit] to make the examples self-contained so that others can work on them without an extraneous dependency. • there’s also the rest of my comment about making a [mre], please review

I think the issue here is that public update and filter are declared without types which is why they are being inferred as any. First, you want to explicitly declare types for public update & public filter. You should then bind them so that they have access the necessary member data.
Example:
export class Todos extends CrudService<Todo, TodoFilters> {
  public update = super.update.bind(this) as typeof 
      CrudService<Todo, TodoFilters>.prototype.update;
  public filter = super.filter.bind(this) as typeof 
      CrudService<Todo,TodoFilters>.prototype.filter;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.update = super.update.bind(this);
    this.filter = super.filter.bind(this);
  }
}


This already seems a lot better than typing everything out, although it does have to repeat the type parameters. It doesn't work though - the .prototype.create is an unexpected identifier for the compiler.

Where did .prototype.create come from?

Sorry, in the given example .prototype.update/filter
